Uncover "siunitx" columns in beamer table
I want to uncover siunitx S-columns in a beamer table. Starting from the example in the beamer user-guide, it works partly but not fully with S-columns. What am I missing?
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    % works
    \begin{tabular}{l c c <{\onslide<2>}S S <{\onslide}}
        Class & {A} & {B} & {C} & {D} \\
        X     & 1   & 2   & 3   & 4   \\
        Y     & .3  & 4   & 5   & .6   \\
        Z     & .05 & 6   & 7   & .08
    \end{tabular}

    % does not work
    \begin{tabular}{l S S <{\onslide<2>}S S <{\onslide}}
        Class & {A} & {B} & {C} & {D} \\
        X     & 1   & 2   & 3   & 4   \\
        Y     & .3  & 4   & 5   & .6   \\
        Z     & .05 & 6   & 7   & .08
    \end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


You could use a tabularray:
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<1-2>

  \only<1>{\SetTblrInner{cell{1-Z}{4-Z}={fg=bg}}}

  \begin{tblr}{
    colspec={lSSSS},
    row{1} = {guard},
  }
        Class & A   & B   & C   & D    \\
        X     & 1   & 2   & 3   & 4    \\
        Y     & .3  & 4   & 5   & .6   \\
        Z     & .05 & 6   & 7   & .08
  \end{tblr}    
\end{frame}
\end{document}



Thanks, it almost works. The problem seems to be that the uncovered columns loose their S-column type. I edited the mve to make this visible.

@DRoc see my edited answer

awesome, works like a charm.
